# Fast way to loop through filtered list in reverse?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with a large number of auto-filtered rows (>200,000). I'm trying loop 'upwards' through a column until I find the first cell that's different from the current cell. I can loop 'downwards' through through visible cells by using:

```
For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'check for different value
Next cl
```

I can also loop 'upwards' skipping over hidden rows using:

```
For i = rng.Count To 1 Step -1
    If rng.Cells(i).EntireRow.Hidden Then
    'do nothing
    ElseIf 'check different value
    End If
Next i
```

But with a large number of hidden rows this can take a while to skip over all of them even if there are only a couple of hundred visible rows. I've tried using `rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and stepping backwards through them but it seems to also go through hidden cells.

1. Is there a way to reverse the order of a `For Each` loop?
2. Is there a faster way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You could populate the row numbers to an array using the first approach, then loop through the array in reverse using the second approach.

Comment: You can copy the entire table and you remove duplicates. Then you your Worksheetfunction.find(...). 'For' is aways worst than use Excel functions.

Comment: `I'm trying loop 'upwards' through a column until I find the first cell that's different from the current cell.` I have a question for you. Why do you want to reverse loop? Do you want to do something with the data? If yes, then both tim's and gary's solution will help you. But if you want to work with the rows(ranges) then you will have to adopt a different technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim x As Long, n As Long
    Dim a() As Long
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, vis As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = sht.Range("A1:A1000")

    Set vis = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    n = vis.Cells.Count
    ReDim a(1 To n)
    x = 1

    For Each c In vis.Cells
        a(x) = c.Row
        x = x + 1
    Next c

    For x = n To 1 Step -1
        Debug.Print a(x), sht.Cells(a(x), 1)
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You could build a Collection of the visible cells and then extract them in reverse:

```
Sub Backwards()
    Dim N As Long, col As Collection, RR As Range, r As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Set RR = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
    Set col = New Collection
    For Each r In RR
        col.Add (r.Address)
    Next r
    N = col.Count

    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        Set r = Range(col(i))
        MsgBox r.Address
    Next i
End Sub
```